# Returning a string from a C# console application to VBScript

Tags: c#, vbscript, return-value, synchronous, return-type

On one of my VBScripts, I have to call a C# console application.

AFTER the C# application finishes executing (synchronous), I need to get the output of the C# application, which is a string, into the VBScript.

`System.Environment.ExitCode` in C# only allows an Integer to be returned.

How can I have get the string that is output by the C# application into the VBScript?

I realize that it is possible to save the output of the C# application to a file and read that using VBScript. However, I was looking for something less messy.

Any solutions/suggestions are welcome.

For example: Is there some way to create a DLL and use this to enable a return string value to be passed to VBScript? I am not sure. This is just a thought. Is there a way to create something similar to `Shell.Application` `BrowseForFolder`?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Any particular reason not to use PowerShell for scripting instead of VBScript? It is soooo much easier to call .Net code from PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This script is being executed from within a 3rd party application which only supports VbScripts.

Comment: I found a better answer than all those provided here in that link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a99a8b0d-fb49-4caf-8107-fc04bd48d3f9/how-to-make-a-main-method-of-a-console-based-application-to-return-a-string-type?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `WScript.Shell` object to execute the C# process, and then read from it's `StdOut` filestream.

For details, see this [tek-tip on the subject](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3330).

Comment: For details I'd rather refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a).

Comment: On the C# program, how can I write to the Stdout so that it will be read by the VbScript?

Comment: @slayernoah Console.WriteLine writes to standard output.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Is there any way we could get it to work the same way without the `WScript.Shell` object? The environment it runs in doesn't have this object. Thanks!

Comment: @slayernoah How are you running  VBScript?  WScript.Shell is part of the Windows Scripting host, which is what runs VBScript...

Comment: @ReedCopsey The VBScript is being executed from within a 3rd party application. When the VBScript runs from within the 3rd party app, any `WScript` references do not work. For example, `WScript.Echo` doesn't work as well so we need to use `Msgbox`

Comment: @slayernoah Using `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` fails?  They must sandbox it somehow... Not sure of another option.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, it returns an Object required WScript error. Also, for your solution above, is it mandatory that the C# app be a console application?

Comment: @slayernoah No - you can read from any process standard output using this -but you would need some way to hook into it - WScript.Shell is the only one I know of in vbscript (I'm not a vbscript guru by any stretch, though ;) )

Comment: Is there a way to hide the command prompt window that calls the C# application?

Comment: @slayernoah Not that I know of.